# Piece of music suddenly drops an octave in guitar pro 6; How can I have it one octave higher?

Tags: software, guitar-pro

I downloaded a piece of music from the internet and whilst listening to it, after a slide, the lead guitar suddenly drops an octave lower. There are no signs on it saying why it's dropped there are not any signs saying it's dropped.
Is there a way to have the rest of the song an octave higher from that point onwards?

Comment: Could you link to the file ?

Answer (score 5):

Without the file, here are the reasons I can think of why GP's playback could switch to another octave without any change to the notes :

- The ["play this an octave lower than written" symbol (8vb)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave#Notation) is enabled but not visible (bug, hidden, you didn't see it ?). Select a note and check on the left panel if it is enabled.
  [image: 8vb button]
- There is an octaver effect that is enabled during the playback. Check the effect panel and maybe watch the video [Handling effect variations](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/200635751-Video-GP6-arrangements-Effect-variations)
- The "clef" changed somewhere in the tab, check that there isn't an [octave clef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef#Octave_clefs) ("normal" treble clef but with an "8" under it) on the bar where the pitch drops.
  [image]

If none of these apply, please provide a link to the file.
If you just want to make it sound one octave higher, apply the reverse of any of the items above, the easiest being to apply a "8va" on the bars that you want to shift.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple: Select the bars you want to transpose one octave higher, like so:

[image]

and go to **Tools>Transpose**:

[image]

Make sure to select "**Selection**" (So as to transpose only your selected bars). Select which tracks you want to transpose. By selecting "**Current Track**", like myself, you're going to transpose only the current track, which in my case is bass and in yours a guitar. Finally, select how many semitones you want your transposition to be. For a full octave, select "**+12(perfect octave)**":

[image]

And you're done:

[image]

Comment: This works for multiple bars as well.